# How can I encrypt password and send through httpservice in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am sending password text to the http service request object.like `<request><password>pass.text</password></request>` now this password I am giving in navigate url also.but password is visibleing when load url and it is hacking.
how can I encrypt password string and send it to jsp?

Comment: Keep in mind that a swf file can easily be decompiled. Hashing password in the flash file is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use as3Crypto:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/as3crypto/

That supports a large variety of both one way and two way encryption schemas.

Answer (score 1):

try a simple hashing, there are quite a few algorithms in the corelib in https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib (see the crypto section).